# Python dict different key names

Tags: python-3.x

Is it possible to loop through a python dictionary like and come out with this output

```
prods = {'product_1': {'color': 'White', 'whls': '25.00', 'size_3': '0', 'size_4': '14', 'size_5': '35'},
'product_2':{'color': 'Black', 'whls': '55.00', 'size_7': '10', 'size_7.5': '13', 'size_8': '35'},
'product_3':{'color': 'Blue', 'whls': '65.00', 'size_6': '15', 'size_8': '11', 'size_10': '29'}}
```

I would like the output to look like this if possible

```
White - size_3 - 0
White - size_4 - 14
White - size_5 - 35

Black - size_7 - 10
Black - size_7.5 -13
Black - size_8 - 35

Blue - size_6 - 15
Blue - size_8 - 11
Blue - size_10 - 29
```

I know how to loop through a normal dict with same keys, but these all have different key names, not sure how i can do this, and if it's even possible.

This is the code i have so far

```
for p in prods:
        for i in prods[p]:
            print(prods[p].get('color') + " - " + prods[p].get('size_') # This is where i get stuck, since all size keys are different
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have the static prefix `size_` present in all/some of the keys of dictionaries then you can use a conditional statement to print the information needed for all sizes.

```
for product_id, product_info in prods.items():
    print()
    for k, v in product_info.items():
        if k.startswith("size_"):
            print(f'{product_info["color"]} - {k} - {v}')
```

`product_id` can be replaced by `_` because it's not used anywhere.